# node.js net.server connections limited to ~1000?

Tags: node.js

I'm running node.js v0.10.22. I create a server like this:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    //stuff
}).listen(8080);
```

I run the file using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH

ulimit -Hn 8192
ulimit -Sn 8192

node myserver.js &>/dev/null &
```

As you can see, I'm setting the number of file handles (hard and soft limit) to 8192. But when I have about 1000 open connections to this server, I can no longer connect. I get an immediate "Connection closed by foreign host" from telnet.

I can't find any option on the net.server in node.js's documentation for setting the maximum number of simultaneous connections. There's server.maxConnections, but changing it has no effect on this problem.

What connection limit setting am I overlooking?

Comment: Did you check if those `ulimit` values are actually sticking? `ulimit -Hn 4096 && ulimit -n`